# Animation of http://responsive-nav.com/ gets choppy on Android

Tags: javascript, css, plugins

I just found out about this really cool plugin (new for me, old for some of you maybe) and it works like a charm upon implementation, but only in regular computer browsers. When I try it on my android phone, the css3 animation of the dropdown moves really really choppy, just like its dropping frames. How can I fix this problem?

Here is the plugin I am reffering to:

http://responsive-nav.com/

Answer (score 0):

They seem to have done a really nice job with the plugin, I would say the largest cause of the drop of frame rate may be because you are repainting the entire screen. If you would like, roll your own side navigation but make it go over the existing web page rather than move all the elements on the screen.

**EXAMPLES OF SIMPLER MOBILE NAV** *without repainting*

http://fringewebdevelopment.com/
http://www.sony.com/index.shtml

As a further step you can also get rid of the javascript and just do plain CSS and see how that works for you, an example of using checkboxes and labels to control the side nav can be found on my site (just inspect the code) - www.aktof.ca . Hope this helps!